# how to use jQuery selectbox plugin for five element at the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have 3 select box at the same page, and i wanna use jQuery selectbox plugin for all 3 selectbox.

The problem is that plugin works only the first element ... and the rest remain normal.

someone know why is that?

my code look like this:

```
  <select class="ex">
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
    </select>


  <select class="ex">
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
    </select>


  <select class="ex">
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test</option>
    </select>
```

and my js code look like this:

```
$(".ex").selectbox();
```

Comment: The plugin seems to be working as intended.  Have a look at this fiddle. [http://jsfiddle.net/xy5LU](http://jsfiddle.net/xy5LU/)

Perhaps there are other conflicts within your code and hence it's not working.  Without more details and/or code samples it's hard to say why it's not working in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

[.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) documentation

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ex").selectbox();
});
```

or

[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) documentation

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    $(".ex").selectbox();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the listbox are loaded before you call the selectbox plugin code.
And if not already put your code inside  $( document ).ready().